# how can I manipulate input value in JS to re-display in my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to grab the input number value in HTML (everytime it's being changed by the user), do some math formula with the value, and re-output the data (without reloading) on the page.

my HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

QTY: <input type="number" name="qty"  value="1" min="0" max="100" id="qty" ><br>
$<span id="total"></span>
```

my JS:

```
<script>
var qty = 1;
var total; 
qty =  setInterval(function() {ObserveInputValue($('#qty').val()); }, 300);

total = qty * 85;
$("#total").html(total);
</script>
```

and JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bcxL3usw/

Not sure where my error is. I think I may have to put `$("#total").html(total);` in the setInterval function, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: use angularjs for the same, it will be easy

Comment: @Sajeetharan angularjs ? can you show me how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function() { 
$("#total").text($('#qty').val()*85);
}, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
QTY: <input type="number" name="qty"  value="1" min="0" max="100" id="qty" ><br>
$<span id="total"></span>
```

**UPD:**

```js
setInterval(function() {
  let x = 0;
  if (parseInt($('#qty').val()) < 3) {
    x = $('#qty').val() * 85;
  } else {
    x = $('#qty').val() * 100;
  }
  $("#total").text(x);
}, 300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
QTY:
<input type="number" name="qty" value="1" min="0" max="100" id="qty">
<br>$
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: how can I play with the value even more, say if(qty < 3, * 85) and if(qty > 3 * 100) ... something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`keyup` function will help you  and also in span you don't use `val()` use `html` or `text()`
https://jsfiddle.net/bcxL3usw/8/

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to do it with pure JavaScript and event listeners:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var target = document.querySelector('#total');
var multiplier = 85;

// Copy over initial value
target.innerHTML = input.value * multiplier;

// On every keyup event, update the value
input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  target.innerHTML = event.target.value * multiplier;
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsmolinski/bcxL3usw/11/

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `change` event instead of an interval which would be a MUCH cleaner way and effecient then recalling to append data when it is not needed:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#qty', function(){
  var qty = $(this).val();
  var total = qty * 85;

  $("#total").html(total);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/77qd65ku/1/)